# async await with promise all

Tags: node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

I want to know if I am using promise.all correctly with async await.

Basically, I need to get the house data based on the ID, then I need to get all the reviews for that house as well as the count of reviews.

```
  server.get("/api/houses/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const house = await House.findByPk(id);
    if (!house) {
      return res.status(400).send("No house found");
    }

    const reviews = await Review.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        houseId: house.id
      }
    });

    house.dataValues.reviewsCount = reviews.count;

    const results = await Promise.all([house.dataValues, reviews.rows]);
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
```

In the front end when I console.log the response after making the http request, I get back the below which seems okay since Promise.all gives you arrays. But I don't know if this is the best way to do this or if there is a better way.

```
[
  {
    id: 2329,
    host: 2,
    picture: '/img/houses/1.jpg',
    type: 'Entire house',
    town: 'Some town',
    title: 'Some title',
    price: 50,
    description: 'Some description',
    guests: 4,
    bedrooms: 1,
    beds: 2,
    baths: 1,
    wifi: true,
    reviewsCount: 2
  },
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      houseId: 2329,
      userId: 1,
      comment: 'An awesome review',
      createdAt: '2019-01-11T22:00:00.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2019-01-11T22:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      houseId: 2329,
      userId: 2,
      comment: 'Another awesome review',
      createdAt: '2019-01-11T22:00:00.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2019-01-11T22:00:00.000Z'
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `Promise.all` correctly. The code is working, because you're `await`ing each promise individually.

Since `Review.findAndCountAll` depends on `House.findByPk` result, `Promise.all` won't do any good here.

You're using `Promise.all` with the already resolved values of the both promises, so you can just drop it.

```
 server.get("/api/houses/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const housePromise = await House.findByPk(id);


    const reviews = await Review.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        houseId: house.id
      }
    });

    house.dataValues.reviewsCount = reviews.count;

    res.send([house.dataValues, reviews.rows]);
 });
```

---

Basically you're doing:

```
const res = await Promise.all([1, 5]); // [1, 5]
```

Which can be translated directly to:

```
const res = [1, 5];
```

---

Instead of sending it in an array, I think it's better to send an object:

```
{
   house: house.dataValues,
   reviews: reviews.rows
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, okay. Thank you! It still sends back the data in an array so is it correct in saying that to get `house.dataValues` I would use for example `props.house[0].title` and for the reviews `props.house[1].comment`

Comment: Yeah, that does look a lot nicer when I get it on the frontend!

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore `async await` and use `Promise`.  You can try following code

```
server.get("/api/houses/:id", async (req, res) => {
   const { id } = req.params;

   return House.findByPk(id)
     .then( house => {
        // !house might be 'true' if house is 'undefined'
        if( house === undefined || !house ) {
           return res.status(400).send("No house found");
        }

        return Review.findAndCountAll({ where: {  houseId: house.id } })
           .then(reviews => {
              house.dataValues.reviewsCount = reviews.count;
              return {house, reviews};
           })
           .catch(error => res.send(error));
      })
      .then( result => {
         return res.send(results);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          return res.send(error);
      });
   })
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use async/await